# Does back pressure with subject and multicast observable?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex, monix

I'm wondering how back pressure works when there are multiple subscribers?

For example with a publish subject in monix or with a observable.publish, or with a ConnectableObservable.

I understand with a ConcurrentSubject, there is a buffer so backpressure is limited or disabled. However, I'm not sure how it works with a publish subject.